# How can I create multiple users that can only edit and create articles/categories for their own permission group?

Tags: joomla-3.x, administrator, user, permissions

I have a website that has lots of companies on it. I want every company to have its own login where they can create categories and articles for themselves but only for themselves, they should not even be able to see articles and categories from other companies.

How can I do this? I am struggling with the permissions function in joomla and no matter what I've tried, when I log in as a company I still see all other articles and categories.

Can someone help me out on how to do this? I am on the latest Joomla version 3.9.18.

Comment: Do you only want them to not see articles and categories from companies only when they are editing and managing their own articles and/or not be able to see other companies in the public or front end view as well?

Comment: And are you wanting them to create or edit articles in the back end or the front end?

Comment: @Irata Only in the backend, I am not using the front end of Joomla.

Comment: Are you not using the front end at all, or just not for the creating and editing of articles? I am curious what your circumstances are if there is no front end view of the articles entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would suggest is the following:

Set up user groups for each of the companies and set the users of that company to belong to that company user group, and only that company user group.

You'll have to give those company user groups access to the administrator login (global config) and also give them access to the "Special" Viewing Access Level so that they can see the admin menu.

Create Viewing Access Levels for each company and set the "User Groups Having Viewing Access" to each of those access levels to be just the user group for that company.

Set up top level categories, one for each company, and set the Access on that category to be the Viewing Access Level you set up for that company.

Go into the Permissions for each of those top level categories, and allow actions by the company user group who has that category and deny actions for other companies.

So for example:

For company C-one set up

User group: C1

Viewing Access Level: "C1Access", with User Group having viewing access "C1"

User: "c1user" with Assigned User Group "C1"

Top level Category: "CatC1" with Access set to "C1Access"

If you've already got other categories on the system you will need to set them so that the user groups of the companies don't have access to them.

Comment: Following the above I found that I still needed to do an extra step to get the Content menu to appear in the back end. I had to go into the Global Config for Articles and set Allowed to 'Access Administration Interface' before it appeared for my Company user group. An alternative I tried was to add Companyx user group a child of the Manager user group rather than follow the instructions in the third paragraph, however this does show a handful of core Components that may need their View levels changed, but does appear to be less effort if there will be a lot of company user groups involved.

Comment: A comment for anyone else that finds this solution. Any articles/categories created by the approach will not be visible to the Public/Guest visitor. They will need to be logged in and have appropriate View Level access given to the desired articles and categories.

Comment: Thanks man this works great!